# Watch .oni files on Mac

Tags: macos, file, watch

is there a way to watch .oni files on Mac (OS X 10.10.2). I just need to watch them. I tried to install Openni following this tutorial http://www.theworldneedsmoredreamers.net/using-openni-2-2-beta-on-os-x/, but it didn't work for me.

Thank you!

Comment: Ask at [apple.se] instead.

Comment: "Watch" as in be notified of changes or as in view?

Comment: I just need the RGB of the file.

Comment: I think "watch" means "view".